# How to send count of log messages to Graphite using Log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I am trying to use this module https://metrics.dropwizard.io/4.1.2/manual/log4j.html, in order to have counters in Graphite for the number of warning and error messages that are logged.

Anyway, when I add the needed dependency, and use the prescribed log4j configuration as per the documentation https://metrics.dropwizard.io/4.1.2/manual/log4j.html, I get the following errors when I run my application locally:

```
2020-03-31 11:34:28,706 main ERROR Appenders contains an invalid element or attribute "MetricsAppender"
2020-03-31 11:34:28,716 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "metricsAppender" for logger config "root"
```

I use the following configuration:

```
<Configuration status="INFO" name="log4j2-config" packages="com.codahale.metrics.log4j2">
<Appenders>
    <MetricsAppender name="metrics" registryName="shared-metrics-registry"/>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="INFO">
        <AppenderRef ref="metrics" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I have the metrics-log4j dependency added to my POM, as the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
    <artifactId>metrics-log4j</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
```

My working environment: Spring Boot 2 + Maven + Java 11

How to overcome these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Log4J 2 but the metrics library you are using is for Log4J 1. Try using [Dropwizard metrics for Log4J 2](https://metrics.dropwizard.io/4.1.2/manual/log4j.html).